# the proper way to callback a value and append it nodejs electron

Tags: callback, electron

hi i have a node module called bonjour, and uses this function to search for devices on the LAN 
`bonjour.find({ type: 'HTTP' }, 
    function (service) {
     console.log('Found an HTTP server:', service)})`.
 Plus  i want to retrieve the the result "service" which is an object and  put the data in a paragraph,  all that in electron so any help is welcomed that you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about collecting `service` objects into a array and then processing that array such as needed.

```js
let services = []

bonjour.find({ type: 'HTTP' }, function (service) {
  console.log('Found an HTTP server:', service)
  services.push(service)
  // and eventually show list of actual services in some node
  document.getElementById('myParagraf').innerHTML = '<ul><li>' + services.join('</li><li>') + '</li></ul>'
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer this helped me alot